# How to get tooltip to display only on column header name on a Kendo Grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid and I am hiding the top row showing all the headers. I am doing this to give it a cleaner appearance and the users should know instantly the data in each column after some use.

I want to add the column names in the tooltip of each cell in case a new user comes in, they can hover over the data and see the column name.

I have the code below but I need to know how to target the column name.

```
myGrid.kendoTooltip({
    filter: "td",
    content: function (e) {
        var target = e.target;
        return $(target).text();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myGrid.kendoTooltip({
        filter: "th[data-title]",
        content: function (e) {
            if (e.target) {
                var target = e.target;
                return $(target).text();
            }
        }
    });
```

Modified the filter  to "th" in order to show tooltip on column headers. Further modified with [data-title] to only show tooltip where there is a title. Thus, disabling tooltip or mouseover on columns with no title. Online resources say to add [title] but that alone does not work. Hopefully this helps someone.